# Why do I get two different results over a string and a vector

Tags: c++, c

I have two strings s1: `"abcd"` and s2: `"ab"` and two int vectors v1: `12,13,14,15` and v2: `12,13`. I am calculating the distance between the two strings and the two vectors. I have got the code from the web for a `c` file to calculate the distance between the two strings. I am modifying the code in a way to calculate the distance between two vectors, but in `c++`. The code is working, but the result are not the same 
(the distance should be the same for both calculations). The problem comes from:

```
double transpositions = 0.0;    
for (i = 0; i < s1_len; i++) {
    if (!s1_matches[i]) continue;
    while (!s2_matches[k]) k++;
    if (s1[i] == s2[k]) transpositions++;
    k++;
}
```

The `s1_len` is `s1_len(s1)` (the same for s2) and the `s1_match` is `int *s1_matches = (int*) calloc(s1_len, sizeof(int))`. 
I am running the `c` code with correct answers, but when I change the code to `c++` and change the string variables to vector variables, the number that I get for `transposition` is different.
To change the string to vector, I get the size of the vector (`v1_len`) by `v1.size()` and the`v1_match` by `int *v1_matches = (int*) calloc(v1_len, sizeof(int))`.
The code is exactly the same:

```
double transpositions = 0.0;    
for (i = 0; i < v1_len; i++) {
    if (!v1_matches[i]) continue;
    while (!v2_matches[k]) k++;
    if (v1[i] == v2[k]) transpositions++;
    k++;
}
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: As an aside, surely you should use an integer datatype for `transpositions` instead of a floating-point datatype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not seem to do any bounds checking on `s2_matches` or `v2_matches`.  This will have undefined behaviour when `s1` and `s2` are not identical:

```
while (!s2_matches[k]) k++;
if (s1[i] == s2[k]) transpositions++;
k++;
```

*ie* You never check for `k` overflowing the bounds of `s2` or `s2_matches`.  Same with the vector version.

Comment: No, don't rely on that.  It is there to protect you against errors.  Just check `k < s2_len`.